# AngularJS file explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am not sure how to go about doing this in an angular way.

I would like to implement a file explorer similar to the following: [example 1](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/gdd11-modern-web-apps/index.html#15) or [example 2](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/demos/upload_directory/index.html#)

features it should implement are:

- show files and folders in current directory
- ability to click on folders to expand them (like in example)

So what i have at the moment is a list of files and folders as an array of paths. This is generated by an onDrop or onChange event (from drag and drop or input).

Any advice on how to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take look at [@angular-filemanager](https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager)

```
FileNavigator.prototype.buildTree = function(path) {
    var self = this;
    var recursive = function(parent, file, path) {
        var absName = path ? (path + '/' + file.name) : file.name;
        if (parent.name && !path.match(new RegExp('^' + parent.name))) {
            parent.nodes = [];
        }
        if (parent.name !== path) {
            for (var i in parent.nodes) {
                recursive(parent.nodes[i], file, path);
            }
        } else {
            for (var i in parent.nodes) {
                if (parent.nodes[i].name === absName) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            parent.nodes.push({name: absName, nodes: []});
        }
    };

    !self.history.length && self.history.push({name: path, nodes: []});
    for (var i in self.fileList) {
        var file = self.fileList[i].model;
        file.type === 'dir' && recursive(self.history[0], file, path);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

[Angular Treeview](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview)

Pure AngularJS based tree menu directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Angular Filesystem Reader](https://github.com/singhketan/angular-filesystem-reader).

> An angular service implementation to find files by extension(s) asynchronously and synchronously, by traversing the filesystem starting from the specified root directory. Exclusive and/or ignorable directories can be specified as well. Three options available to access the results: callback, Promise (sync) and/or a live array (async).